# Using GIT and a CDN for static content

Tags: git, version-control, amazon-s3, cdn

**Problem:**

I have an app that I deploy using GIT. When I want to update the files on my server I do a simple `git pull` to get the latest version of the app from the GitHub repo. The thing is I sort of want to serve all static content from my Amazon S3 account but want these files to be in sync with the version on the main server.

**Questions:**

1. When I `git pull` my project from GitHub how can I pull these files to my S3 account?
2. If I want to switch version on my server (via a tag) how can this then be mirrored on my S3 account?

Comment: Did you ever decide on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, welcome to the world of content versioning.

This is not a GIT question, but actually a common problem when trying to sync static content served from one location to versioned content (from source control) served from a different location.
A common usecase is a website with both dynamic and static content.
A random example is [hotels.com](http://hotels.com). If you inspect the pictures on the front page you will see URLs such as [this one](http://www.hotels.com/static/media/d2241a0f-4677-44ba-8c61-32ee8e59f570_20120518025155424.jpg). Obviously the name of this resource is auto-generated by an `Asset Manager`.

We use Django and Python for some tasks, hence the usage of [Django Mediagenerator](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-mediagenerator). 
We generate a versioned-named directory of static files which we upload to S3.

As you can see from [this comparison](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/), there are plenty of other options out there!
As a bonus for using asset managers you also get compression, obfuscation, merging etc.

In a different part of the application we manually version the files. I auto-calculate a python module of file hashes (a hash per each static file). I upload the static files to S3 while renaming the files to append the MD5 hash of their content. This way some_file.txt becomes some_file_123123123123.txt on S3 and I can download the specific version of the file from S3. The module with the hashes is stored in source control (GIT).

Answer (score 1):

I think, [Git hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) should do what you want. Maybe post-checkout (for switching tags) or post-merge (for pulling) are sufficient. You would then have to write a bash script, which copies your static files to your S3 and execute that bash script in the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful, in case you use PHP for your application (otherwise this code can be adapted to your needs):
https://github.com/SupersonicAds/git-hook-php-s3-files-revisions